# How to assign multiple values for a matrix in R?

Tags: r

I have a 93060-by-141 matrix file with filled values.
I need to assign zeros to some rows and columns with the condition: Row 1: 65 of column 1; row 67:131 of column 2; row 133:197 of column 3 and so on.
This condition excludes for some column, i.e the values in rows of column 10,20,36 are unchanged.

I think I will need a For-loop. But I have no idea how to code for the link of rows and columns expressing the mentioned condition.

Comment: On SO we do not do ... "and so on". If you have an algorithmic rule to specify **unambiguously**, then make your best effort to put it down in natural language. There are ways to economically assign values to matrices, but your responsibility is to post a working example that matches the complexity of your problem. (Hint; It's going to be smaller than 93060-by-141. I'd suggest an example that is 40 x 15))

Answer (score 2):

You can change multiple values by providing a matrix of indexes to a matrix.  The indices correspond with the row (first column) and column (second column) numbers of the cells.  For example doing `mymat[cbind(1:10, 1)] <- 0` would change the first through tenth rows of column 1 to zero. In you case, you could put together several such `cbind()` statements with a call to `rbind()`.  For example, `mymat[rbind(cbind(1:5, 1), cbind(6:10, 2))] <- 0` would change the first through fifth rows of column 1 and the sixth through tenth rows of column 2 to zero.  In the example you proposed above, it would be something like this:

```r
my_mat[rbind(
  cbind(1:65, 1), 
  cbind(67:131, 2),
  cbind(133:197,3))] <- 0
```

Comment: Thank you so much! with rbind and cbind, I concern it may add more columsn and rows to my existing matrix, instead of replacing the values in desired rows and columns.

Comment: @ThuyHangDuong Dave has shown you a method (with unfortunately no explanation and is the reason for my downvote) that would NOT add more columns or data. The method he is proposing (which should succeed for the values you offered) uses a two-column matrix for indexing to the `[<-` function. Sorry, Dave, but there is a long-standing rule on SO that code-only answers are  shall we say ... not the best. The reaction of  the OP is evidence of the reason for that rule (which was formerly explicitly stated) but has apparently been softened in the effort to be more welcoming?

Comment: Thanks, @IRTFM for a nudge in the right direction.  I'll be better about explaining what I propose.